# twilio send sms message Invalid phone number

Tags: c#, sms, twilio

Using this url, https://www.twilio.com/user/account/developer-tools/api-explorer/message-create , I have this Verified/To Number "+923005186330", its working fine and i am getting success "Response 201",  But at c# console application, calling twilio.SendSmsMessage, having same number "+923005186330", I am getting Rest Exception message: "The 'To' number 923005186330 is not a valid phone number." I also tried US Number (949) ***-****, and it was working fine from my c# console application, why it is not working for this number "+923005186330"

Comment: The error message states what is wrong. The number is not a valid phone number. Standard phone numbers are 10 digits like this: 0123456789 with the +1 appended to the beginning. The only suggestion that I could have would be to add the 1 after the plus symbol. Twilio may need it for sanitization purposes.

Comment: prefix is country code, so i have +92 in my case, If you notice "+" sign in To number is not showing in exception message.

Comment: hi ToastyMallows, yes this number is verified. I am getting sms using this https://www.twilio.com/user/account/developer-tools/api-explorer/message-create, but i am getting Invalid exception when i call SendSmsMessage from my c# application. strange thing is why "+" is missing in exception message "The 'To' number 923005186330 is not a valid phone number."

Comment: I just saw that you said Verified, my bad.

Comment: Norman, could you post your code where you make call? If you are passing in parameters, could you debug your application and rather post a screen shot of the values that are contained in the parameters? This will certainly help us find the problem

Comment: For interest sake, you say that you verified the number, did you not then perhaps want to use the verified number as the from parameter instead of the to parameter as you stated in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was problem with lastest version of Twilio, so 
Below version works.

PM> install-package twilio -version:3.6.18
PM> install-package RestSharp -Version:104.4.0

Answer (score 1):

We experienced the same problem and the reason is because Twilio do not support all of its functionality to all countries. If you don't find your country in this CSV file https://www.twilio.com/resources/rates/international-phone-number-rates.csv probably this is the reason why you get this error.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem in various HTTP clients because they didn't correctly encode the `+` character. Try sending it as "%2B923005186330" instead and see if that works.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, due to his question this line twilio.SendSmsMessage would suggest that he is using the Twilio nugget package, and I can confirm that it does work correctly with having a + before the number.

Comment: string AccountSid = "********************************";
string AuthToken =  "********************************";
var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
var from = "+12027937605";
var to = "+923005186330";
var message = twilio.SendSmsMessage(from, to, "hi JR, I am testing twilio API", "");

if (message.RestException != null)
{
var error = message.RestException.Message;// handle the error ...
}, I used NuGet(  <package id="RestSharp" version="105.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Twilio" version="3.6.23" targetFramework="net45" />
)

Comment: onething more if i give US Number in To number like (949) ***-****, it works, but still not understand why it is not working with (+923005186330), wondering it is working at "https://www.twilio.com/user/account/developer-tools/api-explorer/message-create"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you contact the support team on, help [at] Twilio dot com. Provide them with your message Sid's and they will be able to help you track down the issue. It will be much easier for you to resolve this issue that way, as we cannot see all the logs or attempt to duplicate the same result ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

This is bug for the version-3.6.23 .
You can download the old version .

PM> install-package twilio -version:3.6.16 
PM> install-package RestSharp -Version:104.4

Comment: PM> install-package twilio -version:3.6.18
PM> install-package RestSharp -Version:104.4